# How to merge two arrays into one array in angularjs?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, underscore.js

This is my code

```
$scope.studentDetails=[];

$scope.studentDetails=[0][id:101,name:one]
                      [1][id:102,name:two]
                      [2][id:103,name:three] 

$scope.studentMarks=[];

$scope.studentMarks=[0][id:101,marks:78]
                    [1][id:102,marks:89]
```

i have two arrays,first array contains 2 properties like id and name, second array contains two properties like id and marks,i want to concatinate these two arrays into one array.i want to get output like

```
$scope.studentDetails=[0][id:101,name:one,marks:78]
                      [1][id:102,name:two,marks:89]
                      [2][id:103,name:three,marks:null]
```

Answer (score 2):

Lodash [zip()](https://lodash.com/docs#zip) should do that provided your JavaScript is valid in the first place.

`$scope.studentDetails = _.zip($scope.studentDetails, $scope.studentMarks);`

Answer (score 1):

I got the answer

```
var newArray = [];
_.each($scope.studentDetails,function(obj))
{
 var data=_.findWhere($scope.studentMarks,{"id":obj.id});
 if(!_.isUndefined(data))
 {
   newArray.push({id:obj.id,name:obj.name,marks:data.marks});
 }
else
 {
newArray.push({id:obj.id,name:obj.name,marks:"null"});
 }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Hey you can use the push like

```
$scope.studentDetails.push({'id':'101','name':'one','marks':'78'});
$scope.studentDetails.push({'id':'102','name':'two','marks':'78'});
$scope.studentDetails.push({'id':'103','name':'three','marks':'78'});
```

using loop you can append like bellow

```
for(i = 0; i < studentResult.length; i++){
    $scope.studentDetails.push(studentResult[i]);
}
```

Comment: i have number of records and data get from services dynamically.

Comment: You can push the data using loop.

Answer (score 0):

For object array [_.zip](http://underscorejs.org/#zip) merged two array into single array where each array element also an array.

You can use  [*.map*](http://underscorejs.org/#map)  and [.extend](http://underscorejs.org/#extend) to create merged object array with [_.zip](http://underscorejs.org/#zip) like

```
var studentDetails = [{ id: 101, name: 'one' }, { id: 102, name: 'two' }, { id: 103, name: 'three' }];
var studentMarks = [{ id: 101, marks: 78 }, { id: 102, marks: 89 }];

var mergedArray = _.zip(studentDetails, studentMarks); //where each element also an array like [ [{ id: 101, name: 'one' }, { id: 101, marks: 78 }] ]

var studentDetails = _.map(mergedArray, function (item) { return _.extend(item[0], item[1]); }); //[{ id: 101, marks: 78, name: 'one' }, ..]
```